# Sum() and count() are not working together with agg in pyspark2

Tags: pyspark

I am using json data file “order_items” and data looks like

```
{“order_item_id”:1,“order_item_order_id”:1,“order_item_product_id”:957,“order_item_quantity”:1,“order_item_subtotal”:299.98,“order_item_product_price”:299.98}
{“order_item_id”:2,“order_item_order_id”:2,“order_item_product_id”:1073,“order_item_quantity”:1,“order_item_subtotal”:199.99,“order_item_product_price”:199.99}
{“order_item_id”:3,“order_item_order_id”:2,“order_item_product_id”:502,“order_item_quantity”:5,“order_item_subtotal”:250.0,“order_item_product_price”:50.0}
{“order_item_id”:4,“order_item_order_id”:2,“order_item_product_id”:403,“order_item_quantity”:1,“order_item_subtotal”:129.99,“order_item_product_price”:129.99}

orders = spark.read.json("/user/data/retail_db_json/order_items")
```

I am getting a error while run following command .

```
orders.where("order_item_order_id in( 2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) ").groupby(“order_item_order_id”).agg(sum(“order_item_subtotal”),count()).orderBy(“order_item_order_id”).show()
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: ‘int’ and 'str’

I am not sure why I am getting ...All column vales are string. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Cast the column to int type. Can’t apply aggregation methods on string types.

Comment: Thanks Sathish...now I am getting different error

orders.groupby("order_item_order_id").agg(sum(int("order_item_subtotal")),int(count())).orderBy("order_item_order_id").show()

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'order_item_subtotal'